# How to re-insert an element if it was removed?

Tags: javascript, html, output, display

So, I need your help figuring out how to remove an element that is not permanently when a function is triggered, so that I can then recall the removed element.
Here's the problem: when I activate the `getPlanets` function, I get the results I want and if the output of the `getCharacters` function is activated in the meantime, it disappears. However, the reverse does not happen: when I activate the `getCharacters` function while the output of the `getPlanets` function is active, it does not disappear and I end up with two outputs on the screen.
I tried to fix this with

```
if (ctnPlanets) {
const ctnPlanets.remove ()
}
```

but I got another bug: when I click on the `getPlanets` function again, I get the blank screen, because the HTML `ctnPlanets div` has been removed and the output is not displayed.
I also tried to clone the element, to write functions that would create it again when activating `getCharacters,` but I could not get any results. After

```
if (ctnPlanets) {
const ctnPlanets.remove ()
}
```

the result is as if the `div of ctnPlanets` was no longer there and it was not possible to recreate it.
The result I want to obtain is that when `getPlanets` is activated, the output of `getCharacters` disappears and there is only that of `getPlanets.` On the other hand, when you activate `getPlanets,` the output of `getCharacters` must disappear and there must be only that of `getPlanets.` However, in both cases the result does not have to be definitive, because then the user must be able to return to the output of `getPlanets` or `getCharacters,` depending on the situation. What I have now, however, is that clicking on `getCharacters` after clicking on `getPlanets`, I have two outputs on the screen.
Thanks to anyone who can help me!
This is my code:

JS:

```
const ctnPlanets = document.getElementById("ctn-main");
const ctnPlanetsClone = ctnPlanets;

async function getCharacters() {

  if (document.getElementById("characters") != null) {
    return;
  }
  const square = document.createElement("div");
  square.setAttribute("id", "characters");
  document.body.append(square);
  square.style.cssText = "background-color: blue; width: 1200px; height: 1200px; margin: auto; margin-top: 2.5%; display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; flex-direction: row";

  const people = fetch("https://swapi.dev/api/films/2/").then(data => {
    return data.json();
  }).then(films => {
    films.characters.forEach(url => {
      const request = fetch(url).then(d => d.json()).then(character => {    
        const wrapper = document.createElement("div")
        square.append(wrapper);
        wrapper.style.cssText = 'width: 250px; height: 200px; margin: auto; margin-top: 5.5%;'
        wrapper.innerHTML = '<div><h1>' + character.name + '</h1>' + 
        '<h3><p>Birth Yearh: ' + character.birth_year + '</p></h3>' + 
        '<p>Gender: ' + character.gender + '</p></div>';
      })      
    })    
  }) 
}

async function getPlanets() {

  const firstFunctionOutput = document.getElementById("characters");
  if (firstFunctionOutput ) {
    firstFunctionOutput .remove()
  }

  document.querySelector('.overlay').classList.add('active');
  let results = await fetch(URL_Planets);
  const data = await results.json();
  nextPlanets = data.next;
  previousPlanets = data.previous;
  planets = data.results;
  let outPut = '';

  document.querySelector('.overlay').classList.remove('active');
  planets.forEach(item => {
   outPut += `<div class="card card-planet">
                  <h2>${item.name}</h2>
                  <h5>Climate: ${item.climate}</h5>
                  <h5>Terrain: ${item.terrain}</h5>
                  <h5>Population: ${item.population}</h5>
               </div>`         
  })
  ctnPlanets.innerHTML = outPut
}
```

HTML

```
<main id="main">
      <div id="ctn-main" class="ctn"></div>  
    </main>
```

Comment: The reference to the DOM element is kept in constant `ctnPlanets` despite of removing the element from the DOM. Just remove `const` from `const ctnPlanets.remove()`.

Comment: It gives me an error report in the console: "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Assignment to constant variable."

Comment: Don't try to re-assign a value to `ctnPlanets`, just re-append it. Take a look at [a working example](https://jsfiddle.net/L96cb0ux/).

Comment: WOW! Thank you very much! I really spent A LOT of time searching a solution. HOURS!

Comment: Just sorry for asking @Teemu, but why i need to write a `setTimeout`? Why id doesn't function without a `setTimeout`?

Comment: It does work without the timeout, the timeout in my example is for demonstration only. Notice, that your example code doesn't contain `ctnPlanets.remove()` nor an attempt to re-attach it to the DOM, we don't know how you're actually using it.